# VF Issue: Contacts not re-rendered with new values

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to display list of accounts and when user clicks on any account it should display the contacts associated with that account..

But the problem is it displays contact details only for the account we click on for the first time after that any account we click on, It does not refresh the contact details..

Here is My Code:

Controller Class:

```
public with sharing class CustomAccountController {
    public CustomAccountController() {

    }

    public Id selectedAccountID {
        get ;
        set ;
    }

    public List<Contact> contactList{
        get ;
        set ;
    }

    public List<Account> getmyAccounts(){
        return [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 30];
    }

    public void getmyContacts(){
        contactList =  [SELECT Firstname,LastName FROM Contact WHERE AccountID=:selectedAccountID];
    }

}
```

VisfualForce Page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="False" showHeader="False" controller="CustomAccountController">

<apex:form>
    <apex:dataList value="{! myAccounts}" var="Acc">
    <apex:commandLink action="{! getmyContacts}" reRender="ContactDetails">
        <apex:outputText value="{! Acc.Name}" />
        <apex:param assignTo="{! selectedAccountID }"  value="{! Acc.Id}" />
    </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:dataList>
</apex:form>

<apex:outputPanel id="ContactDetails">
    <apex:repeat value="{! contactList}" var = "contact">
        <p> {! contact.FirstName} {! contact.LastName}</p>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a name to the `<apex:param />`

Example:

```
<apex:param name="selectedAccountId" assignTo="{!selectedAccountId}"  value="{!Acc.Id}" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much..But i have one questions..I tried with any value for the name attribute and it is working..So it can be any value?

Comment: there is a known salesforce bug where parameters do not work without a name. but it can be any name